# Most reliable way to return a subset of a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have spent the better part of the morning looking for opinions on this issue - and while I noticed a lot of people stumble across it and post similar questions here, I was not really able to find a sufficient answer or solution. This must be such a wide-spread problem that I am either blind, or the question has never been fully discussed. I am using PHP, but the question is more or less primarily related to MySQL.

**Imagine this MySQL query (just a random example):**

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    users.firstname,
    users.lastname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT images.id, '|', images.url) as images
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    assoc_users_images ON assoc_users_images.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN
    images ON images.id = assoc_users_images.image_id
GROUP BY
    users.id
```

The query should return all users with images that are connected to them via a connection table. Use case could be a social network where users are "tagged" on photos. At the moment, I am exploding the result for "images" in a PHP loop.

I chose this example because the amount of photos a user is tagged in could become extremely high and I just recently had the case where a whole application broke because I forgot to take into account the character limit for `GROUP_CONCAT`. So at least at this point I had the impression that GROUP_CONCAT is extremely hacky for what I want to do.

I wonder: What are better ways to solve this and to avoid `GROUP_CONCAT` at all? I know that MySQL can't return arrays, but there must be a way to solve this both efficient and elegantly?! Should I make another query? At which point? Should I query for images separately and bring everything together on the software side?

Comment: I wouldn't use `GROUP_CONCAT` just to parse it again on the server-side and split them with '|'. But anyway you could set `GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN` to any value temporary or golabaly.

Comment: In your question you say you are looking for opinions. SO guidelines clearly say that opinion based questions are not allowed.

Comment: @GertB. Every answer is an opinion in the end. I think there must be a pretty clear solution to this issue, so I think a pretty clear answer IS possible. If it should be the case that there is no good way to solve it and just different workarounds exist, I happily delete the question as it would be indeed misplaced here.

Comment: @SoheilRahsaz Thanks, setting up the max length worked and I didn't know it can be extremely high. Nonetheless, this feels like a really bad solution prone to cause errors at multiple points. I would still be interest if there is a better way to solve it...

Comment: `Every answer is an opinion in the end`...no, the vast majority of them are factually correct e.g. "this code demonstrably fixes your bug". Whether you like it or not, this site explicitly doesn't accept opinion based questions - see the [help/on-topic]. But actually your question is arguably just badly phrased - you  _do_ have a bug: you're sometimes exceeding the character limit for group_concart. Now, mySQL doesn't return arrays but it's very good at returning result sets which you can then loop through in PHP. So yeah just return all the images in a result set.

Comment: If you want a quick-and-dirty solution, you could use MySQL's JSON support to return a serialized JSON array with `JSON_ARRAYAGG` rather than `GROUP_CONCAT`. (It would be better to limit the # of tagged photos with a subquery, so not posting this as an answer. This function has a ~8k limit, `GROUP_CONCAT` ~1k by default)

Comment: Yes, I could have posted this bug and my code, but I thought the phrasing like this and demo-code that is easier to understand than my application code (where no-one has any chance to understand what the query does) might be better for the long-term usability of this post. Thanks to anyone that is willing to offer answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` has a limitation indeed, but luckily you can change it, like

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

If you want to permanently set its maximum value, then you will need to change it in the config, like

```
[mysqld]
group_concat_max_len=15360
```